# call mysql query each 5 seconds

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

i am trying to call mysql query contents automatically based on time farm to display it as one line show the contents of mysql query

i was able to make the timer function but i couldn't implant it with the ajax function to call the mysql query automatically

what i need is put the variable which i made in the `loop()` function in the ajax function `showUser(str)`

here is my html with javascript and ajax code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script>


var x=0;
function loop() {
    x= x+1;
if (x == 100) x = 1;
document.getElementById("timevar").innerHTML=x;    
setTimeout("loop()", 5000);     
}    loop(); 

function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true); \\ timevar should be instead of str
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
<option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
<option value="3">Glenn Quagmire</option>
<option value="4">Joseph Swanson</option>
</select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

timevar should be instead of str or giveing it's value to `showUser` function

here is php code on the page which called getuser.php :

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'peter', 'abc123');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("ajax_demo", $con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '".$q."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Comments</th>
<th>Clicks</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Age'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Comments'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Clicks'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

what i am trying to do is making each name with it's info to appear and flip at the same line .. i don't want them to appear in a table .. am trying to make it more dynamic

any help appreciated .. thank you so much

Comment: Well worth looking at a JavaScript library such as jquery & using PDO for your php db access.

Comment: i could access db through getuser.php page which works fine .. but i couldn't call it by a variable each 5 seconds .. all what i need is a way to make the `showUser` function set it's value to a variable which is defined as x from 1 to 100 .. as u see i could call the db via the form onchange , but i don't want that .. i want it to change by time .. thank you @Tboy Allen :)

Answer (score 2):

You might find that using jQuery to handle your ajax calls may make your life easier.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

```
    $.get('ajax/callmySQL.php');
```

Comment: thank you @twisterghost for advice .. i was able to get and call db .. i want db to be called automatically each 5 seconds

Comment: Well in that case you should just use a simple setInterval() call on a function containing the ajax. When you use setInterval, it will call whatever code you want every X milliseconds. Try `setInterval(myFunction, 5000)`

Comment: you right @twisterghost .. and that's what i did but by complicated method :) i think  .. thank you soo much for help

Answer (score 1):

You really should take a look on jQuery. It makes life a lot easier. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

jQuery's $.get calls callbacks when request is done. You simply update document from them and setup timer for next request.

Something like:

```js
function update() {
    $.get(url, null, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $('#txtHint').html(data);
            setTimeout(update, 5000);
        });
}
setTimeout(update, 5000);
```

Btw, there is no need for passing code as string, you can enter function name directly: `setTimeout(loop, 5000);`

Comment: i haven't deal with jQuery's before i'm reading about it now .. am still confused .. i will keep reading and i hope i find something soon :) .. thank you @Josef Kufner

Answer (score 0):

i found what i was looking to .. it was just because am slowly learning and new to javascript :)

i had the answer all the time but i didn't knew how to write it and now i knew :)

i define the variable `timevar` which i knew it should be there .. now i define it by putting it in a function as increasing number go +1 each 10 seconds then i put it again in the loop after interval for 10 seconds

i think i write too many things which i don't need there .. but after all it works find :)

here is the answer maybe it helps someone somewhere sometime

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true); // timevar should be instead of str
xmlhttp.send();
}

var setdelay=10000 //delay 10 seconds
var timevar=0;

function moveit(how){
if (how==1){ //cycle foward
if (timevar<100)
timevar++
else
timevar=0
}
else{ //cycle backward
if (timevar==0)
timevar=100
else
timevar--
}}

setInterval("moveit(1)",setdelay)

var x=0;
function loop() {
    x= x+1;
if (x == 100) x = 1;
showUser("timevar");
setTimeout("loop()", 10000);     
}    loop();
</script>
</head>
<body onload="loop()">

<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```